# JQ function work just twice

Tags: jquery, function

```
check = false;

$("#sidebar").click(function() {
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("playsidebar");
    if (check == false) {
        $("#div").css({ "padding-left": "300px" });
        check = true;
    } else {
        $("#div").css({ "padding-right": "300px" });
        check = false;
    }
});
```

Thats a function is open a side-bar when the button is pressed. The function is actually works fine for the first and two times, but after that its just open and close the side-bar without actually padding left or right.

Someone can understand whats wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You never remove the `padding-left` or `padding-right` that you set...

Comment: What you mean? @RoryMcCrossan . When im doing padding-left 300px and then padding-right 300px its the oppsite and then its back to normal

Comment: @Roy: No, `padding-left` and `padding-right` are entirely separate things.

Comment: So what I should do instead of the padding-right to cancel the padding-left? @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Thanks, I saw it and its work. I can click the accept answer button in 4 minutes and ill do it! @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're changing `padding-left` on the first click, and `padding-right` on the second. Sounds like you want to change `padding-left` back again on the second click.

What you're doing (note the yellow highlight, so we can see the padding on `#div`):

```js
var check = false;

$("#sidebar").click(function() {
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("playsidebar");
    if (check == false) {
        $("#div").css({ "padding-left":"30px" });
        check = true;
    } else {
        $("#div").css({ "padding-right":"30px" });
        check = false;
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
sidebar
</div>
<div id="div">
<div style="background-color: yellow">
div
</div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
wrapper
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You probably wanted

```
$("#div").css( {"padding-left": "0px" });
```

instead:

```js
var check = false;

$("#sidebar").click(function() {
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("playsidebar");
    if (check == false) {
        $("#div").css({ "padding-left":"30px" });
        check = true;
    } else {
        $("#div").css({ "padding-left":"0px" });
        check = false;
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
sidebar
</div>
<div id="div">
<div style="background-color: yellow">
div
</div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
wrapper
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: With jQuery's `css` function, when specifying numeric properties like `padding-left` and such, you can just use a number; jQuery will handle the `px` for you:

```
$("#div").css({ "padding-left":30 });
```

Side note 2: When only setting a single property, you can avoid creating the object (and making jQuery deconstruct it) by using two arguments:

```
$("#div").css("padding-left", 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
check = false;

$("#sidebar").click(function() {
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("playsidebar");
    if (check == false) {
        $("#div").css({ "padding-left": "300px", "padding-right": "0" });
        check = true;
    } else {
        $("#div").css({ "padding-right": "300px", "padding-left": "0"  });
        check = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Code dumps are usually not *useful* answers. Explain *what* you changed, and *why*. (But I'm fairly sure the OP doesn't want `padding-right` at all.)